# how to HTTPS for ALB Requests in Laravel 9.x route()

Tags: laravel

ALB redirects HTTP to HTTPS and forwards HTTPS traffic to the target group's port 80. The target group uses Nginx to receive the requests and communicates with PHP-FPM via a socket.

When using route('my-route-name') to generate URLs, I expected the URLs to be in the format https://host.example.com/path/to since the AWS ELB (ALB) is included in the TrustProxies configuration. However, the generated URLs are in the format http://host.example.com/path/to.

What else do I need to configure to get the desired URLs?

I don't want to use forceScheme().
Prior to using ALB, in the environment where Nginx was used as a reverse proxy, https was created.

app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    protected $proxies = '*';

    protected $headers =
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;

}
```

resource/views/mypage.blade.php

```
  ....
   <a href="{{ route('my-route-name') }}">link text</a>
  ....
```

.env

```
  ....
   APP_URL=https://host.example.com
  ....
```

expected

```
<a href="https://host.example.com/path/to">link text</a>
```

actual

```
<a href="http://host.example.com/path/to">link text</a>
```

$request->header() contains the following keys:

```
 "x-forwarded-port"
 "x-forwarded-proto"
 "x-forwarded-for"
```